# What is the right way to insert objects with several nested associations in sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to create an object with several nested associations using a transaction. I'm using Postgres and the objects are the following:

```
var Product = sequelize.define('product', {/* attributes */});
var ProductDetail  = sequelize.define('productDetail', {
   id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
   /* attributes */
});
var ProductVariation = sequelize.define('productVariation', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    /* attributes */
});

Product.hasMany(ProductDetail);
Product.hasMany(ProductVariation);
```

And I tried to create a transaction to insert the new product and the correspondent associations all at once:

```
return models.sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
    return models.product.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        enabled: req.body.enabled,
        productDetails: req.body.productDetails,
        productVariations: req.body.productVariations
    }, {
            include: [models.productDetail, models.productVariation],
            transaction: t
        }
    )
}).then(function (result) {
    //Success
}).catch(function (error) {
    //Shouldn't rollback?
});
```

And I get an error `[ReferenceError: product is not defined]`. Also the transaction is not getting rolled back because I can see a new product in the database.

The error suggests that the product does not exists when it tries to created the associations. That's odd since after throwing the error the product is the only thing created.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the error was elsewhere. The associations I was trying to create already had an "id" (that was being used temporarily in the client side) when it should be generated by postgres through sequelize (with DEFAULT) and was resulting in this error.

I don't know why this particular error: `[ReferenceError: product is not defined]` was thrown but after removing the "id" attribute from both it started to work.

Sorry to put you on a wild goose chase.

Answer (score 0):

ReferenceError is a Javascript error, not a sequelize error.

You simply have to replace `product` by `Product` when you call create() because you instantiate the variable with a capital letter.

Comment: That's not correct. It was created with lowercase in "sequelize.define" and that's what counts. Also the product is being created is the associated objects (productDetail and productVariation) that aren't created and throw the error that product is not defined.